# Problem solving: parentheses in C with given String

Tags: c

I am currently trying to code that but my program is not working as it should. The program is getting a String and it should look whether the String has balanced parentheses or not. We are using a special library, but the standard one should also work. Only three test cases don't work and I really don't know how to fix them, tried multiple things and it just got worse.

```
#include "base.h"

#define MAX 30000
int top=-1;
int stack[MAX];

void push(char);
char pop();
bool match(char a,char b);

bool match(char a,char b)
{
        if(a=='[' && b==']') return true;
        if(a=='{' && b=='}') return true;
        if(a=='(' && b==')') return true;
        if(a=='<' && b=='>') return true;
        return 0;
}/*End of match()*/

void push(char item)
{
        if(top==(MAX-1))
        {
                return;
        }
        top=top+1;
        stack[top]=item;
}/*End of push()*/

char pop()
{
        if(top==-1) {
                exit(1);
        }
        return(stack[top--]);
}/*End of pop()*/
bool verify_parentheses(String text) {
    // TODO
    int i;
    char temp;
    for(i=0;i<strlen(text);i++) {
        if(text[i]=='(' || text[i]=='{' || text[i]=='[' || text[i]=='<')
            push(text[i]);
        if(text[i]==')' || text[i]=='}' || text[i]==']' || text[i]=='>')
            if(top==-1) {
                    return true;
            } else {
                    temp=pop();
                    if(!match(temp, text[i])) {
                            return false;
                    }
            }
    }
        if(top==-1) { /*stack empty*/
                return true;
        } else {
                return false;
        }
}

int main(void) {
    report_memory_leaks(true);

    test_equal_i(verify_parentheses(""), true);
    test_equal_i(verify_parentheses("Hello World"), true);
    test_equal_i(verify_parentheses("()"), true);
    test_equal_i(verify_parentheses("<{[()]}>"), true);
    test_equal_i(verify_parentheses("<{[)]}>"), false); 
    test_equal_i(verify_parentheses("( Test ) "), true); 
    test_equal_i(verify_parentheses("(1+2)*[2+3+(1 + 6/5)]"), true); 
    test_equal_i(verify_parentheses("(an unmatched left parenthesis creates an unresolved tension that will stay with you all day"), false);
    test_equal_i(verify_parentheses("< [ > ]"), false); 
    test_equal_i(verify_parentheses("<{[()]}"), false);
    test_equal_i(verify_parentheses("(<<({[({<{<({<([[[<[{(<{(<{{<[{<{{{<<{([<<<{{[{<<[[(([{[[[([(({()}))])]]]}]))]]>>}]}}>>>])}>>}}}>}]>}}>)}>)}]>]]])>})>}>})]})>>)"), true);
return true;
}
```

Comment: You should properly handle the errors in `pop` and `push`. `exit(1)` for a `pop` from empty stack will cause the program simply exit in some unbalanced cases.

Comment: What cases doesn't work? Is it possible to minimize those tests? Have you tried to *debug* the failing tests, for example by using a debugger to step through the code statement by statement while monitoring variables and their values?

Comment: Unrelated: In `match` you return `true` or `0`. I suggest making that `true` or `false`.

Comment: This code is hard to read. Please use consistent indention and preferably either 2 or 4 spaces wide.

Answer (score 0):

I took your code and edited the pop function, and also changed the returned data type in some of your functions,your logic still remains so you should be able to read the code. It appears that every time you were popping the stack you were not decrementing 'top'. In the main function I used my own way to verify whether the brackets do match , you can use your own function it should still work or you can pass your test case strings into the existing one.

```
#include <unistd.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <string.h>
    
    
    #define MAX 30000
    int top=-1;
    int stack[MAX];
    
    void push(char);
    void pop(int *stack);
    int match(char a,char b);
    
    
    int match(char a,char b)
    {
            if(a=='[' && b==']')
              return 1;
            if(a=='{' && b=='}')
              return 1;
            if(a=='(' && b==')')
              return 1;
            if(a=='<' && b=='>')
              return 1;
            return 0;
    }/*End of match()*/
    
    void push(char item)
    {
            if(top==(MAX-1))
            {
                    return;
            }
            top++;
            stack[top]=item;
    }/*End of push()*/
    
    void pop(int *stack)
    {
            if(top==-1) {
                    exit(1);
            }
            stack[top] = 0;
            top--;
    }/*End of pop()*/
    int verify_parentheses(char *text) {
        // TODO
        //char temp;
        for(int i=0;i < (int)strlen(text);i++) {
            if(text[i]=='(' || text[i]=='{' || text[i]=='[' || text[i]=='<'){
                push(text[i]);
            }
            if(text[i]==')' || text[i]=='}' || text[i]==']' || text[i]=='>'){
                if(top==-1) {
                        return 1;
                } else {
                        
                        if(!stack[top])
                          return 0;
                        if(!match(stack[top], text[i])) {
                                return 0;
                        }else{
                          pop(stack);
                        }
                }
            }
        }
            if(top==-1) { /*stack empty*/
                    return 1;
            } else {
                    return 0;
            }
    }
    
    int main(void) {
    
      if (verify_parentheses("<{[()]}>"))
        write(1, "OK\n", 3);
      else
        write(1, "Error\n", 6);
        //report_memory_leaks(true);
    
        //test_equal_i(verify_parentheses(""), true);
        //test_equal_i(verify_parentheses("Hello World"), true);
        //test_equal_i(verify_parentheses("()"), true);
        //test_equal_i(verify_parentheses("<{[()]}>"), true);
        //test_equal_i(verify_parentheses("<{[)]}>"), false); 
        //test_equal_i(verify_parentheses("( Test ) "), true); 
        //test_equal_i(verify_parentheses("(1+2)*[2+3+(1 + 6/5)]"), true); 
        //test_equal_i(verify_parentheses("(an unmatched left parenthesis creates an unresolved tension that will stay with you all day"), false);
        //test_equal_i(verify_parentheses("< [ > ]"), false); 
        //test_equal_i(verify_parentheses("<{[()]}"), false);
        //test_equal_i(verify_parentheses("(<<({[({<{<({<([[[<[{(<{(<{{<[{<{{{<<{([<<<{{[{<<[[(([{[[[([(({()}))])]]]}]))]]>>}]}}>>>])}>>}}}>}]>}}>)}>)}]>]]])>})>}>})]})>>)"), true);
    return 0;
    }
```